# How to add a value from database as minutes on a specific time with strtotime

Tags: php, mysql

I want on this variable:

```
$start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($_POST["start"]));
```

to add a specific time (on minutes) that will be parced from a form to this variable:

```
$end;
```

The code that I think that will work is:

```
$durationQ = "SELECT duration FROM services WHERE '$titlee'=service_desc limit 1";
$durationResponse = mysqli_query($connection, $durationQ);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($durationResponse)){
$currentDuration = $row;
}
$end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+".$currentDuration." Minutes", strtotime($start)));
```

I think that it works practically but In action it doesnt have any result the $end variable. Can anyone see any bug that I cant see?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

You can do something like the following:

```
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start)
  ->modify(sprintf('+%d minutes', $currentDuration))
  ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Your code is showing me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$time = new \DateTime($start);
$time->add(new \DateInterval('PT' .  $currentDuration . 'M'));
$end = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```